# Finding Homology of Koszul Complex

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R = \mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ and $I = \langle x,y,z\rangle$. I have the free resolution of $R/I$ as

$K : 0 \rightarrow R \rightarrow R^3 \rightarrow R^3 \rightarrow R \rightarrow 0$

I need to find the $H_1(K)$ which is equal to $\ker (\phi_1)/ \operatorname{im} (\phi_2)$.

But I am stuck here. I know the maps explicitly but I am not being able to find what is it exactly. I am guessing as this is a regular sequence the homology would be zero, so that sequence would be exact. But how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

The minimal free resolution, $K$, of $I=\langle x,y,z\rangle$ is given by

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}0 @>>>R@>\begin{pmatrix}z\\-y\\x\end{pmatrix}>>R^3 @>\begin{pmatrix}-y&-z&0\\x&0&-z\\0&x&y\end{pmatrix}>>R^3@>\begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\end{pmatrix}>>R@>>>0\\\end{CD}$$

From this, we get that:

$$\ker(\phi_1)=\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-z\\0\\x\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\-z\\y\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle=\text{im}(\phi_2)$$